# Prove that $A\cup (X \setminus A) = X$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a set containing $A$.

Proof: 
$y\in A \cup (X \setminus  A) \Rightarrow y\in A$ or $y \in (X \setminus A)$

If $y \in A$, Then $y \in X$ because $A \subset X$.

If $y \in (X \setminus  A)$, Then $y \in X$ and $y \notin A$. So $y \in X$.

Therefore $y \in A \cup (A \setminus X) \Rightarrow y \in X$.

Now I've proved that every element of $A \cup (A \setminus X)$ is also an element of $X$.
But how to prove vice versa??

Comment: The "if $A$ then $B$" clause is equivalent to "$A\Rightarrow B$", so it doesn't make much sense to say "If $y \in A$, then $y \in A \Rightarrow y \in X$"

Comment: Your seem to interchang $X\setminus A$ with $A\setminus X$.  They are utterly different.  Which do you mean?  Also you shouldn't say "a set containing $A$".  You should say "$A$ is a subset of ".

Comment: @fleablood Yeah only at one place. I corrected and thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reverse implication is simple enough.

If $y \in X$, then either $y \in A$ or $y \not \in A$, since $A$ is a subset of $X$.

If $y \in A$, then $y \in X$ since $A \subseteq X$ is given.

If $y \not \in A$, since $y \in X$ is also given, then $y \in X - A$.

Therefore, in either case, $y \in A \cup (X-A)$, the desired conclusion.

Comment: In the second(if) step, why did you say $y \in X$? Is it necessary?

Comment: For $y \in X - A$, it is necessary $y \in X$ is true, yes. I mostly wrote that in an explanatory way since, while I don't strictly need to repeat myself from the previous statement of $y \in X$ being given, it just helps the reader understand where I'm going with everything and why it follows. Clarity is never a bad thing (even if it sometimes takes more words and time to establish).

Comment: @Nimantha  Yes, since you wish to show $X\subseteq A\cup(X\smallsetminus A)$, you should begin by assuming $y\in X$ with the aim of deriving $y\in A\cup(X\smallsetminus A)$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I think we two are talking about two different things. I refered to the second "if" statement. There is no doubt we should start by assuming $y \in X$.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Yeah, I totally agree with you. Clarity is never a bad thing. I see now either case leads to the desired conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A\subseteq X$

$\Leftarrow:$

Show

$$X\subseteq A\cup(X-A)$$

Let $\phi_1,\phi_2$ be some formula

write $A=\{a:\phi_1(a)\}, X=\{x:\phi_2(x)\}$

Since $A\subseteq X$ we have for any $t$ that $\phi_1(t)$ implies $\phi_2(t)$

Note that $$A\cup(X-A)=\{t:\phi_1(t)\vee(\phi_2(t)\wedge\neg\phi_1(t))\}$$

To show $X$ is a subset of $A\cup(X-A)$ is same as to show that

$$\forall t,\phi_2(t)\rightarrow\phi_1(t)\vee(\phi_2(t)\wedge\neg\phi_1(t))$$

Which is clearly a tautology

Hence proved

$\Rightarrow:$

Similarly, for another direction we also need the condition $A\subseteq X$, just consider

$$\forall t,\big((\phi_1(t)\rightarrow\phi_2(t))\wedge(\phi_1(t)\vee(\phi_2(t)\wedge\neg\phi_1(t)))\big)\rightarrow\phi_2(t)$$

Not hard to see, it's also a tautology

Which proved $A\cup(X-A)\subseteq X\tag*{$\square$}$

Answer (score 1):

The inverse is really trivial.

Proposition:  For any sets $A, B$ than $A \subset A\cup B$.

Pf: If $x \in A$ then ($x\in A$ or $x \in B$).  So $x\in A\cup B$.

So $A\subset A \cup (A\setminus X)$

Comment: It's not clear "For any sets $A,$ $B$ than $A \subset A \cup B$"

Comment: Then read the proof.  If $x \in A$ then ($x \in A$ or $x \in B$) is true as $x \in A$ or $x \in B$ then $x \in A\cup B$.  So $A \subset A\cup B$.  This should be obvious.  $A\cup B$ is the set containing all the elements of $A$ and $B$-- so it contains all the elements of $A$.   This should be as obvious as "If Jim is bigger than Caitlin and Sheila, then Jim is bigger than Sheila".

Comment: What is to be proved is not that A is included in the union of A and of A-X. What has been proved is actually trivial but does not answer the question. For the goal is to prove that  set X ( not  set A) is included in the union of A and of A-X.